# Hibernate update changes record in db, but future requests still return cached values?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm updating a record via hibernate with the following code:

```
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        User u =  (User) session.get(User.class, userId) ;
        u.fooBar = newFooBar;
        session.update(u);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
```

When I execute this code, I can see in my database that the value of the column `fooBar` for the user has changed. However in future requests, when queries are made which would fetch the same `User`, its `fooBar` value is the same as it was before updating. If I restart my web server, then the value updates.

Is Hibernate simply caching the old values? How can I force it to update its cache values when the object is updated?

Comment: Hibernate caches the old value only if you keep using the same session without ever closing it. Each request should open a session, start a transaction, do its job, commit the transaction and close the session. Also note that the call to `session.update()` is unnecessary.

Comment: @JBNizet I'm doing `sessions.getCurrentSession()` at the start of the request, in order to get the session. And I have `hibernate.current_session_context_class` set as `org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext` in my `hibernate.properties`. But the values still aren't updating on future requests

Comment: The server doesn't start a new thread for each request. It uses a pool of threads and reuses them. You must make sure to close the session at the end of the request.

Comment: @JBNizet So `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().close()` at the end of each request?

Comment: Actually, no. The [javadoc of ThreadLocalSessionContext](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/context/internal/ThreadLocalSessionContext.html) explains clearly what you should do: get the current session, begin a transaction, do your job, and commit/rollback the transaction. The session is automatically closed when the transaction is committed/rollbacked.

Comment: @JBNizet That's what I'm doing, but its not updating the value in future requests even though it has changed in db.

Comment: That's not what you're doing then. The above code, for example, doesn't start a transaction, but commits it. And if an exception happens, neither commit nor rollback is called. Why don't you use Spring or a Java EE container, which would let you handle transactions declaratively, and would deal with session and transaction cleanups for you?

Comment: There is also the unanswered question of how your are accessing the "unchanged" values.  The commit you call does write this to the database but what session are your reads using?

Comment: @JBNizet I'm using GWT so I can't use a different framework on top of it. And in my actual code, I am starting a transaction after I get the session, sorry.

Comment: @user3360944 I'm doing a query like `session.createQuery("From user Where id = :id")` (abbreviated) and then iterating through results. Its those results which have the old value of the user.

Comment: If you asked for a new session before you create the query and then start a transaction you should get the latest data.  FYI GWT can be used with Spring but it is confusing because some of your java code is server side and some gets converted to javascript to run in the browser and the line of demarcation is not clear.

Comment: @user3360944 Yeah, not interested in learning a new framework or porting all my existing code to a new framework at the moment. I am doing `getCurrentSession` at the start of the request and committing transaction at the end.. perhaps its not working as its supposed to?

Comment: Because you are using GWT the getCurrentSession call in your read logic executed at page load.  Have you tried refreshing the page in your browser?

Comment: @user3360944 This code is happening inside an ajax request which is sent after the page has loaded. That should count as its own request, right?

Comment: @user3360944 I.e if i have multiple ajax requests sent, each request should get its own session via `getCurrentSession`, right?

Comment: They are all probably getting the same session because the GWT code all executes at page load.

Comment: @user3360944 But the hibernate stuff is happening on the server, not in GWT code which is on the client. The client just sends ajax requests to the server, and on the server, `getCurrentSession()` is called in response to each request.

Comment: So your Hibernate code executes in a servlet?

Comment: @user3360944 Exactly.. yes.

Comment: Then each doGet or doPost should begin a get the currentSession create a new transaction and commit or rollback that transaction.  The Spring framework will do this for you automatically by marking the servlet @Transactional but sometimes the old ways are best.

Comment: @user3360944 Porting my code to spring isn't an option, but I'm already doing `getCurrentSession().beginTransaction()` at doGet/doPost for each request, and doing `getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit()` at the end of the request.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49304/discussion-between-user3360944-and-click-upvote)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start each servlet get with a new transaction and close it when you are finished you should get the most recent data.

The code to do this is getCurrentSession().beginTransaction() and t.commit() or t.rollback()